# TypeError: stream.removeListener is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, typeerror, enzyme

```
We are using jest("jest": "20.0.4") and enzyme("enzyme": "^3.3.0") to write unit test cases for react component. npm test is throwing below error :
TypeError: stream.removeListener is not a function
      at BufferedConsole.Console.<computed> (internal/console/constructor.js:245:12)
      at BufferedConsole.log (internal/console/constructor.js:282:26)
      at ExternalResultsTable.render (src/components/externalResultsViewer/index.js:595:17676)
      at finishClassComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14741:31)
      at updateClassComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14696:24)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15644:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19312:12)
      at workLoop (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19352:24)
      at renderRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19435:7)
      at performWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20342:7)
```

Unable to find any helpful resources online to help resolve this issue. Also there is no direct reference to the method/function stream.removeListener in our codebase.

Comment: Hi, do you have any external dependency in externalResultsViewer/index.js?

Comment: Nothing noteworthy -  we are using standard react libraries and external libraries like React,axios,moment,AgGridReact,react-icons, some lodash functions, connect from react-redux, some Custom CSS.

Comment: It seems node is causing this, what version of node are you using?, see https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: We are using Node - v10.13.0

Comment: Did you check this, https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/491, Also check if you have  babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs & babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node to babel-jest